# get all nodes in YAML with same name by python

Tags: python, yaml

How to get all the values of the nodes with same name e.g. title defined in the YAML to a list by python.

```
name: test
article:
   title: title1
paper:
   title: title2
blog:
   title: title3
```

Comment: Do you have any code written by you to solve it?

Comment: How do you want the data to be structured? Do you want a dict of titles with each type like this:

`{'title' : {
    'article' : 'title1',
    'paper' : 'title2',
    'blog' : 'title3'
}}`

Comment: I just want to return ['title1','title2','title3']

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
import yaml

# Define the recursive function
def iter( map, match ):
    output = []
    for key, value in map.iteritems():
        if type( value ) == dict:
            output += iter( value, match )
        if key == match:
            output += [ value ]

    return output

f = open( infile, 'r' )
data = yaml.load( f )
f.close()

print iter( data, 'title' )
```